# Получить содержимое CListCtrl

Tags: mfc

Как пробежаться по всему CListCtrl и получить его содержимое: строки и столбцы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CString GetStr = CListObj.GetItemText(n,m);
```

n - номер строки
m - номер столбца